# How to adjust color of certain features for figure with transparent background

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am saving plots with transparent background to paste on a dark background. I can fix most things, but two things I don't know how to "brighten up" to be visible.

1) The square box of the axes for each of the plots in the figure.

2) That little black "1e11" thing.

I suppose I'd like to do all plots the same if that is simpler, but now my interest is piqued if there is a way to do each separately (e.g. red border for one plot, green for another).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

tau = 2.*np.pi

theta = np.linspace(0, tau)
x = 1.4E+11 + 0.9E+10 * np.cos(theta)
y = 3.3E+10 + 4.5E+09 * np.sin(theta)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
fig.patch.set_alpha(0.0)

ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.08, 0.15, 0.4, 0.8])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.55, 0.15, 0.4, 0.8])

grey1 = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
grey2 = (0.7, 0.7, 0.7)

ax1.patch.set_facecolor(grey1)
ax1.patch.set_alpha(1.0)

ax1.set_xlabel('time (sec)', fontsize = 16, color=grey2)
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize = 16, colors=grey2)

ax1.plot(x, y)

plt.savefig('nicefig')   # don't need: transparent=True
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you want to do these changes selectively for `ax1` or for both / all axes?

Comment: I've modified the question - at the moment I'd need all the same (if that is simpler)

Comment: There are two different approaches. What do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is to change the default settings:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# define colors
grey1 = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
grey2 = (0.7, 0.7, 0.7)

plt.rcParams['lines.color'] = grey2
plt.rcParams['xtick.color'] = grey2
plt.rcParams['ytick.color'] = grey2
plt.rcParams['axes.labelcolor'] = grey2
plt.rcParams['axes.edgecolor'] = grey2

# the rest of your code goes here ....
```

Result:

[image]

However, this will apply the changes to all axes. So if you want to keep the standard colors on `ax2`, you will have to dig into the axes object and find the corresponding artists for all the lines and text elements:

```
# all your plotting code goes here ...

# change the box color
plt.setp(ax1.spines.values(), color=grey2)

# change the colors of the ticks
plt.setp([ax1.get_xticklines(), ax1.get_yticklines()], color=grey2)

# change the colors of the labels
plt.setp([ax1.xaxis.get_label(), ax1.yaxis.get_label()], color=grey2)

# change the color of the tick labels
plt.setp([ax1.get_xticklabels(), ax1.get_yticklabels()], color=grey2)

# change the color of the axis offset texts (the 1e11 thingy)
plt.setp([ax1.xaxis.get_offset_text(), ax1.yaxis.get_offset_text()], color=grey2)

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @uhoh I added the second (selective) approach

Comment: Yikes! I never would have figured those out. Thanks @hitzg